# How to find continuous part of timeline

Tags: r, loops

Given a data frame with gaps in timeline...

```
date         value
2013-09-03       1
2014-03-08       1
2014-03-19    2815
2014-03-20   13403
2014-03-21   26950
```

... what would be an efficient way of finding the first date since which the timeline is continuous? (In the example above, 2014-03-19.)

I have a straightforward solution...

```
dt <- max(df$date)

while (length(df[df$date == dt[1] - 1, 1]) == 1) {
    dt <- append(dt[1] - 1, dt)
}
```

... but as I have to loop through loads of data, something more efficient would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following combination of `min` `which` and `diff`:

```
min(which(diff(x$date) == 1))
```

This will give you the first row which is followed by a consecutive date in the next row, in your example, row 3. However, it doesnt check if the rest of the column is also consecutive.

Comment: or use `max` instead of `min` to actually check get the result the OP wants: `df$date[(max(which(diff(df$date)>1))+1):nrow(df)]`

Comment: @shadow good addition, though I understood his question as how to find the _first_ date, in his example 2014-03-19.

Comment: I figured that it was the first date when the difference was no longer larger than 1. So the last date when it is larger than 1 plus 1 day. That does what you call 'checking if the rest of the column is also consecutive'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for useful comments! Now I will get a stopwatch and see how much faster this works :-)

Comment: @Mikhail please tell me you aren't using a literal stopwatch

Comment: I actually did at first, but then switched to using system.time function. With my data, this works roughly 50 times faster than my "straightforward" solution.